# Can I make citep quote author and number?

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I am interested in using `natbib` and `citep` to display both the author and a number. For example, that `\citep{author}` displays `(author [1])`, rather than `[1]` in numbers mode, or `(author, year)` in authoryear mode.

I know that I can manually achieve what I want using `(\citet{author})`, however, it would be nice to automate this with `\citep` to take advantage of `sort&compress` when there are multiple citations.

If there is a solution that combines authoryear and number, that's also great.

The code snippet below is an MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@book{knuth1984texbook,
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin and Bibby, Duane},
  volume={3},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley Reading}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
I want \texttt{citep} to format as (author [1], author[2], and author[3]),
which seems to be a combination of \texttt{authoryear} and
\texttt{numbers}.

I can manually achieve what I want using \texttt{numbers} and \texttt{citet}:
(\citet{knuth1984texbook}, \citet{goossens93}, and \citet{greenwade93}).
If I use \texttt{citep}, the result is multiple numbers within square
brackets \citep{knuth1984texbook,goossens93,greenwade93}.


The Oxford comma is not crucial.

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```